# Expressing a vector as a linear combination in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is it possible to express any vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$
>   as a linear combination of the vectors $[−1,4,1,0]^T$, $[3,2,0,1]^T$, $[1,−1,0,2]^T$ and $[0,1,3,−2]^T$?

This is a problem on a practice test that I was working on but the test has no answers to check my work. I was curious how to prove the above statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: See if the vectors are linearly independent or not!

Four vectors $v_1, v_2,v_3, v_4$ are linearly independent if $c_1v_1+ c_2 v_2 +c_3 v_3 +c_4 v_4 = 0$ implies $c_i = 0$ for each $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the vectors are linearly independent. That is,

$$av_1 + bv_2 + cv_3 + dv_4 =0$$
$$\left[\begin{matrix} -1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & -2 \end{matrix}\right] \left [\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{matrix}\right ] = \left [\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right ]$$
where not all of $a, b, c, d =0$.
Which is equivalent to checking the determinant:
$$\left|\begin{matrix} -1 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 2 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & -2 \end{matrix}\right| = 0 .$$
Or you can do row operations to see if you can get the matrix into the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-1&4&1&0\\
3&2&0&1\\
1&-1&0&2\\
0&1&3&-2
\end{vmatrix}
\neq0,
$$ 
$S=\{(−1,4,1,0), (3,2,0,1),(1,−1,0,2),(0,1,3,−2)\}$ forms a linealy independent set of vectors. Since $\dim\mathbb{R}^4=4$ and $S$ is a L.I. subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$  with $4$ vectors, so $S$ spans $\mathbb{R}^4$. Thus your statement is possible.